# How to deactivate Chrome`s lookalike warnings

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome constantly gets on my nerves, when visiting a site, where Chrome's heuristic thinks it might be a lookalike version of something other, it found in my history (if I understand the principle correctly), e.g. `www.nameofcity-supermarket.example` gets a warning if Chrome sees me visiting `www.nameofcity.example` some times before, and such.

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LookalikeWarningAllowlistDomains policy is not suitable for you, or you want to kill these notices on all domains, here's a permanent solution:

- Delete the contents of "SafetyTips" folder inside your profile
  directory;
- Deny all access to the folder, so Chrome component updater wouldn't be able to create it again.